# What is the highest and lowest comfortable average temperature on a planet?

Tags: planets, temperature

I want to write about a planet that has a high average temperature, but low enough to be comfortable. Just because of curiosity, I would also like to know the lowest comfortable.

Additional Info:

1. Comfortable in my sense means survivable for a long period or indefinitely without much protection/insulation.
2. The inhabitants are regular humans.
3. By without much protection I mean that on a warm planet, they wear shorts and t-shirts and on a cold planet, they wear a jacket and sweatpants.
4. Available technology and resources are identical to what we have now.

Comment: 'comfortable' and 'barely habitable' seem like incompatible criteria. Comfortable seems a matter of opinion - Bedouins and Inuit might strongly disagree about the 'comfortable' range.

Comment: The concept of comfortable temperature is entirely subjective. When my wife is comfortable with the heating temperature at home in winter, I am usually wearing short and tops and sipping bear to cool down...

Comment: comfortable in my sense basically means survivable for a long period

Comment: @i_am_a_smart that really doesn't do anything to limit the scope of your question still. There are peoples who have lived for long periods in just about every environment of the planet. I suggest you do some basic research on how peoples in different environments manage already

Comment: Hello, *i_am_a_smart*, and welcome to Worldbuilding!  Please take our [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the way the site works.  Have a nice day!

Comment: We need additional information.  (a) Are the people human?  (b) what does "without much protection/insulation" mean?  Are they wearing shorts and T-shirts? (c) What resources are available? Wood? Caves? Peat? Shovels? Food?  Water?  It's a pain to start a fire with two sticks, but not impossible. (d) What are the actual conditions? Arid? Desert? Tropical? Finally (e) What is the background of the humans?  Survivalists? Engineers? Pastry chefs? Ex-Cons?  Thanks!

Comment: @L.Dutch If you're "sipping bear to cool down", then you can certainly handle strong drink. :)

Answer (score 2):

To study [comfort temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Room_temperature#Comfort_levels), scientist have usually took a large set of volunteers (1) and placed them in controlled room, with fixed temperature, humidity, ventilation, clothing and physical activity.

Based on the reported impression, they have come with some ranges.

> The American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language identifies room temperature as around 20 to 22 °C (68 to 72 °F), and the Oxford English Dictionary claims that it is "conventionally taken as about 20 °C (68 °F)".
>
> Owing to variations in humidity and likely clothing, recommendations for summer and winter may vary; a suggested typical range for summer is 23 to 25.5 °C (73 to 78 °F), with that for winter being 20 to 23.5 °C (68 to 74 °F), although by other considerations the maximum should be below 24 °C (75 °F) – and to avoid sick building syndrome, below 22 °C (72 °F).
>
> The World Health Organisation's standard for comfortable warmth is 18 °C (64 °F) for normal, healthy adults who are appropriately dressed. For those with respiratory problems or allergies, they recommend no less than 16 °C (61 °F), and for the sick, disabled, very old or very young, a minimum of 20 °C (68 °F).

(1) half seriously my professor at university used to say that usually these volunteers where students or soldiers, both cheap and available in large numbers.

Comment: at 160 degrees F a healthy adult male would only be able to last a few days with constant water

Comment: @ChebiKitty, I would object that "lasting a few days" qualifies for a comfortable environment

Comment: it would be comfortable for you to have to drink a gallon of water an hour until you die 2 days later?

Comment: @ChebiKitty, since 160 F is not mentioned anywhere in my answer but only in your comment, are you arguing with yourself?